# Is it posiible to stop user to enter value in textbox more than length of 5 at runtime in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to stop a user to input value in textbox more than the length of 5 at runtime in HTML. How will it be possible?
Length of value means number of characters in a string ,not range of numbers.Please don't recommend max and min attributes.
[image: It should not let user to input more than 5, It should show errors at runtime]

Comment: Why `maxlength` attribute is not working for you?

Comment: look it - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Comment: It don't show error at runtime and nor stop to enter value in textbox.I want that textbox should lock when it reach its maximum value, in my case 5

Comment: Regardless of this being fixed on the client side, you should make sure that there is also validation for this on the server side later.  You cannot rely on the client to enforce this restriction

Comment: @MehranAyub, do you need `disabled` status when the maximum number of characters?

Comment: Are you using `type="number"` or `type="text"`? Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @sergey kuznetsov yes I need it disable at max value

Comment: @Johnny Mopp  I am using type=" text"

Comment: Disabling it once they reach the max seems like a terrible user interface.  What if the user types the wrong input?  If it is disabled, they cannot fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="5">
```

Comment: Its not working for me. It don't lock textbox at max value.It let user to enter

Comment: @MehranAyub What do you mean with "lock"?! "Disable" the textbox or limit the input to x chars ? Info about browser and your setup would be very informative for this problem "It dont lock textbox"

Comment: @ Marc  'Lock' means limit the input to x chars

Comment: @MehranAyub Then his code works perfectly fine...

Comment: OOH I got it, it was my mistake , I was using type='number' , that's why maxlength was not working. But now its working perfectly with type='text'

Comment: Thanks Dude @Thunderbolt Engineer